# Can I use this camera switcher?

Tags: pwm, camera

I am wondering can I use this bicks camera switcher with the arduino since it uses a PWM signal.[image]

If i can do I just put it on one of the PWM outputs or do I need to wire I add something to make it work.
**You can find the user manual here under attachments.**https://store.bicks.us/multiview/20-bicks-s-multiview-duo-fpv-camera-switcher.html

Comment: what do you mean by `use with arduino`?

Comment: can I use one of the pwm outputs to control it.(https://oscarliang.com/bicks-multiview-duo-camera-switcher/) for further reading

Comment: No one will read the user manual for you. This is not how StackExchange work, you read the manual and write the code, if there is any problem or question, come back here and ask the question.

Comment: Ok Thank you for letting me know

Comment: why not use a digital pin?  the PWM is for control with a radio RC

Comment: good idea, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pwm output of an RC receiver is the same signal used to control a servo. So if you used the servo library with Arduino to control the pwm of this device it should work fine.